# JQuery Invalid or unexpected token on simple code Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am currently trying to create a dynamic rails form that changes based off of a drop down selection. The form has two different award nomination types (Kovaleski and DSA), and I want to dynamically change the fields based on the user's selection.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".kovaleski").hide()
});
```

the above code (written in the application.js file) correctly only loads the DSA fields

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (@nomination.award_name == "Kovaleski"){
    $(".kovaleski").show(); $(".dsa").hide()
}
  else{
    $(".dsa").show(); $(".kovaleski").hide()
  }
});
```

But this code does not work properly, and gives the error "Invalid or unexpected token" in the console. This error has stumped me for days and I'm unsure why I am getting it.

Comment: `@nomination` is not valid javascript. a variable can't start with `@` ,

Comment: @mpm that got rid of the token error, thank you. Any idea on this new one "Uncaught ReferenceError: nomination is not defined"?

Comment: I don't know where nomination is defined at first place, you need to show the code for that.